# export variations products to amazon

Tags: php, amazon-mws

Please anyone help me to understand how to export products with variations to amazon.

i know i have to send:

- product feed
- pricing feed
- image feed
- inventory feed

and the last one is the relationsheep feed.

can someone give a working example of the product feed and the relationsheep feed ? 
i search all over and i couldn't find something, thank very much for the help!

```
<feed><product></product></feed>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, take a look at the [MWS documentation for feeds](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSFeedsApiReference._V135478122_.pdf).

Also, look at the [XML documentation](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V162213417_.pdf), which has some example XML documents, as well as XSD files.

You can also find a [PHP sample application](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/192-4179144-8121723?ie=UTF8&section=feeds&group=bde&version=latest) for feeds.

And, a useful tool is the [MWS scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html), which is a web front end for the various MWS methods.